# How do the Madden Julian Oscillation (MJO) waves originate?

Tags: meteorology

I was reading about tropical cyclones and tropical waves and there I saw a study mentioning its relationship with MJO activities. I saw several research papers which discuss about MJO waves. They only mention that a rising sinking pattern travels eastward at a given speed every 40-60 days.

I could not find any detailed mechanism about how these waves are generated near Africa and Western Indian Ocean. How is the wet-dry pattern formed? Does it have any relation with the high radiation in Northern hemisphere summers? If there is any, do these waves emerge during Southern hemisphere summers too?

Comment: well if you can solve it you can earn yourself the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl-Gustaf_Rossby_Research_Medal :)

Comment: The origin of MJO is a mystery unsolved so far. Theories about it abound though - from mid latitude influences to Kelvin wave interaction etc but none convincing yet though

Comment: https://researchfeatures.com/2018/02/27/weather-pattern-global-tropics-madden-julian-oscillation/

Comment: @gansub maybe you can add an answer summarising the remaining problems and where the current research stands?

Comment: @Agni you will find some useful references in my answer to this question regarding origin of MJO - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13553/why-would-geostrophic-theory-be-invoked-in-the-tropics-with-regards-to-the-mjo/ Check out the references that point to Bin wang.